# Can't set state with axios get request?

Tags: reactjs, parameters, get, axios

So I want to set my state for my bookings to be my result.data, the request is working and I can console.log(result.data). However when I try to set the state and then check that state, it's empty.
What is going on? Does it have something to do with my params I'm passing to axios?

My initial state looks like: this.state = {bookingArrayByDate: []}

Tried setting the state outside "then" but that didn't work either

```
  componentDidMount() {
    let today = moment(new Date())
    let dateToSend = today.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    axios
      .get(
        `http://localhost:8888/booking-backend/fetch-reservation.php/`,
        { params: { res_date: dateToSend } }
      )
      .then((result: any) => {
        console.log(result.data)
        this.setState({
          bookingArrayByDate: result.data
        })
      })
    console.log('this is outside', this.state.bookingArrayByDate)
  }
```

The array at the bottom will be empty when i console log it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is fine. What you are experiencing is the standard asynchronous behavior of`this.setState()`. When you `console.log()` your `state`, there is no guarantee that it was updated in the time between your `setState()` and the `console.log()` execution.

In fact, its almost 100% unlikely that it was changed within that time, because React actually batches `setState()` requests by putting them in a queue until the entire event is completed. In your case, the `setState()` wouldn't actually occur until after the `componentDidMount()` logic finishes.

What you can do is pass a call-back as the 2nd argument to `this.setState()`, that call-back is executed directly after the `state` has finished updating, thus ensuring you are printing the updated `state`.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    let today = moment(new Date())
    let dateToSend = today.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    axios
      .get(
        `http://localhost:8888/booking-backend/fetch-reservation.php/`,
        { params: { res_date: dateToSend } }
      )
      .then((result: any) => {
        this.setState({
          bookingArrayByDate: result.data
        }, () => console.log(this.state.bookingArrayByDate)) <-- you can swap this whatever function you need.
      })

  }
```

Comment: Many thanks! Would it then be logical lets say if I want to run a function after the component did mount, to first run something like getData() and then myFunction(), both inside componentDidMount?

Comment: @piedude hmmm I would say it makes the most sense to use your `componentDidMount()` to call the` getData()` function, then upon updating state, you can do whatever you want in the `setState()` call-back. That is the typical structure of a React component that fetches data from an API. Similar to what I have above, just exchanging the `console.log()` with your function. Let me know if that makes sense.